# How do you use Active Record Enum Radio Buttons in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums, radiobuttonlist

In my app, there is a comment section on articles. I'd like the user to have the ability to comment with 3 different options. To activate this, I am using an Active Record Enum.  Please note that the comment sections is nested under the articles.

```
resources :articles, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :comments
end
```

Migration:

```
class AddEnumToCommentModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :comments, :post_as, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Comment model:

```
enum post_as: %w(username, oneliner, anonymous)
```

I attempted to add this to the content view, but lost. I am guessing I also have to do something in my controller but not sure.

Attempted view :

```
<%= form_for([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <h3>Fill in your comment</h3>
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="post_as">
    <h3> Choose how you want to post your comment :</h3>
    <%= f.input :content, post_as: ???, as: :radio %>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

  <br>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 23):

Rails creates a class method using the pluralized attribute name when you use enum. The method returns a key value pair of strings you've defined and what integers they map to. So, you could do something like this:

```
<% Comment.post_as.keys.each do |post_as| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :post_as, post_as %>
  <%= f.label post_as.to_sym %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7):

There's also [collection_radio_buttons](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons), which is more succinct than the other options.

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :post_as, Comment.post_as, :second, :first %>
```

Those last two arguments specify how to get the input's value and label text. In your example `Comment.post_as` produces a hash of enum key names to the underlying integer, so we can grab those using `:second` for the integer and `:first` for the name — easy!

Here's what that produces:

```
<input type="radio" value="0" name="comment[post_as]" id="comment_post_as_0">
<label for="comment_post_as_0">username</label>
# Etc.
```

You can also customize the HTML by passing a block, which is my preferred way to create enum radio buttons with clickable labels:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :post_as, Comment.post_as, :second, :first do |b|
  b.label { b.radio_button + b.text }
end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

An addition to [xxyyxx's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26555785/1417223) answer, if you want the labels to be clickable as well:

```
<% Comment.post_as.keys.each do |post_as| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :post_as, post_as %>
  <%= f.label "#{:post_as}_#{post_as.parameterize.underscore}", post_as %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the view instead of

```
<%= f.input :content, post_as: ???, as: :radio %>
```

you could have

```
<%= f.radio_button(:post_as, "username") %>
<%= label(:post_as, "Username") %>
<%= f.radio_button(:post_as, "oneliner") %>
<%= label(:post_as, "Oneline") %>
<%= f.radio_button(:post_as, "anonymous") %>
<%= label(:post_as, "Anonymous") %>
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#radio-buttons